# Symfony error 500 with app.php, works fine on app_dev.php

Tags: php, symfony1

I am currently trying to use our (basic) Symfony 2 app by accessing app.php. However, whenever I try to access app.php, I get an error 500. I have checked the logs, the production log is empty. I have tried the assetic entry in the config file, but to no avail. Anyone else who has any ideas on how to fix this?

This is a very basic application (for now), with just some routing changes and a new controller. The most part is html (as a test), so it can't be the php we've written so far.

--edit: I currently do *not* have the documentroot pointing to the /web directory, but I don't have admin rights on the server. However, because the app works in app_dev.php, I don't see how this could be a problem?

Comment: Are the cache and log directories writable, and with the right permissions?

Comment: I've emptied the cache dir and folders were created. Also, the dev log was edited, so yes, I believe they are writable.

Comment: You may need to log at warning level in log file.

Comment: Nope, still nothing :/ (i have edited the action_level FYI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by removing a tab from my .yml config files and contacting the serveradmin to set the directoryroot to /web.

Comment: For me the issue was I had bad permissions on folders. You can find [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) how to setup permissions properly.

Answer (score 19):

The problem also can be caused by changing state of one variable into the **web/app.php** file from `false` to `true`.

Check linie:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

and change to:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Comment: And perhaps it's nice to mention that the kernel constructor typically looks like: `AppKernel($environment, $debug)`. You are thus turning on debugging mode.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but with setting true:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

I managed to get a readable error message. In my case there was a problem with an mysql-table.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little late, but i got same error today, and what helped was clearing cache.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today, and enabling debug mode through AppKernel still didn't show the error. Turned out I had enabled `ApcClassLoader` in `app.php` (just before `AppKernel` is initialized) but APC wasn't yet enabled on the new environment I deployed to. Commenting the `APCClassLoader` bit out again in `app.php` resolved the issue.