# Symfony app-dev.php working, but not app.php

Tags: symfony, iis

I am creating Symfony 2.8 web app. I am working on Windows Server 2012 R2 on IIS, PHP 7. On local server `app.php` and `app_dev.php` are working corectly. But on production server only `app_dev.php` is working, `app.php` throws 500 error. Logs from Symfony, IIS and PHP don't have any useful information, only about access etc. 
 I deleted cache for all envs, [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15743033/3212936) and used `php app/console --env=prod cache:warmup`. Also I've tried to change in `config-prod.yml` monolog settings to log all things like in dev environment.
 To deploy I am using `git clone`.

Comment: If you get an HTTP 500 error, you must by all means try to get the stack trace, or at least the file/line number of the error plus the error message. If you don’t have access to this information, ask someone who can give it to you. If you don’t know where to find it, search. If your log level is too low, increase it and try again … It’s pointless to play guessing games here if debugging information is potentially available.

Comment: Edit app.php and change $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); to $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);  That might generate an error message.  Typically it's a file system access problem.

Comment: Can you check if the twig file that is being rendered in production has the `{{ dump() }}` function being called? That would throw a 500 error.

Comment: @lxg As I mentioned, I have tried all ways to get stack trace.
@Cerad I've tried `true` and `false` without succes...
@AlvinBunk There is no dump. Although at local server it should not work either, am I right?
<br>I found out that some files are missing. Something goes wrong when project was cloning from git.